# Issue Defining ToolTips on ASP.NET DropDownList items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, custom-attributes

I am trying to use the “title” attribute for ASP.NET DropDownList items to display mouseover tooltips for each item.  However, it seems like after I make a choice, and reopen the list, only tooltips for the selected item and below show the tooltips.  For example, if I have 10 items in my list, and choose the 7th one, only 7-10 show tooltips if I re-open the list.

I have done a View Source of the page in the browser, and all the “title” attributes are present, but the upper ones don’t display on mouseover.

If I select the top item in the list, then they all display again.  But if I choose the bottom item in the list, only that item has a tooltip that comes up.

I have tried both defining a derived class from DropDownList and overriding the SaveViewState and LoadViewState, as well as re-adding the attribute on a postback; both show the same behavior.

Comment: In which browser do you see that behavior? (Addendum: according to my tests, it must be in Internet Explorer)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes you are correct, this only occurs in Internet Explorer.  That is the browser that my organization uses.  I wonder if a work around exists.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below to make the selected item go to top of the list and all other items will appear below.

`protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)`
`{`
    `var itemIndex = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;`
    `if (itemIndex != -1)`
    `{`
       `var item = DropDownList1.Items[itemIndex];`
       `DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);`
       `DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));`
    `}`
`}`